# Determine team numbers by looking at the member overlap in two columns

Tags: r

Here is my toy data where person1 and person2 are inputs from which I want to calculate same_team and which_team variables.

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~person1, ~person2, ~same_team, ~which_team,
  112,      576,        "n",           0,
  164,      987,        "n",           0,
  161,      191,        "y",           1,
  191,      161,        "y",           1,
  125,      146,        "y",           2,
  125,      200,        "y",           2,
  146,      125,        "y",           2,
  146,      200,        "y",           2,
  200,      125,        "y",           2,
  200,      146,        "y",           2)
```

Since person 191 is in person 161's row and vice versa they are in the same team. Similarly, though person 576 is in person 112's row, but not vice-versa they are not in the same team.  So, if person1 and person2 are in the same team, I want to say "y" in same_team variable, else "n" and allocate a unique team number under which_team variable. It would be great if I can get the solution in SparkR code.

Comment: So you input data is just the first two columns? How can you tell who is in the same team from that data?

Comment: That's just the variable name to suggest if person 191 is in person 161's row and vice versa they are in the same team. Sorry about the little-confused names.

Comment: I still don’t understand. 112 and 576 are in the same row, shouldn’t they be on the same team?

Comment: If we have one more row with person1 = 576 and person2 =112, then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after:

```
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)

clust <- clusters(graph.data.frame(df %>% select(person1, person2)))$membership
teams <- data.frame(ids = as.numeric(names(clust)), which_team = clust)

df %>%
  left_join(teams, by = c("person1" = "ids")) %>%
  group_by(which_team) %>%
  mutate(same_team = ifelse(n() > 1, "y", "n")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(which_team = ifelse(same_team == "n", 0, which_team - sum(same_team == "n")))
```

It uses the `igraph` package to identify number of different clusters (teams in your case), and then joins this information.

As it seems you want to label everyone who is without a team with 0, so the last line does that with the `ifelse`, while also deducting the number of such individuals from other clusters (as `igraph` automatically recognises even a link between 2 as 1 cluster).

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(person1 = c(112, 164, 161, 191, 125, 125, 146, 
146, 200, 200), person2 = c(576, 987, 191, 161, 146, 200, 125, 
200, 125, 146)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: How will the team numbers be allocated when the number of teams are more say 100 or 1000?

Comment: Have a look at my edit, I think you'll benefit from `igraph` here. Don't have much time so could be done more elegantly but I believe it serves the purpose.

Comment: I'm running this on a `df` with only `person1` and `person2` columns. If you delete others it should work. I've also included my data in the post, and shortened a bit the code.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that later. Thanks!